# v-if="loading" works for md-progress-bar but doesn't work for anything else

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, vue.js, xmlhttprequest

Below is the code I am using:

```
<template>
    <md-table>
        <md-table-toolbar>
            <div v-if="loading">
                <h1> Hi </h1>
            </div>
            <md-progress-bar md-mode="query" v-if="loading"></md-progress-bar>
        </md-table-toolbar>
    </md-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ordered-table",
        props: {
            tableHeaderColor: {
                type: String,
                default: ""
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selected: [],
                files: getData(),
                loading: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            getData: async function (event) {
                this.loading = true;

                this.files = await getData();

                this.loading = false;
            }
        }
    };

    function getData() {
        var url = "http://localhost:4999/";
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send(null);

        return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }

</script>
```

v-if="loading" on the md-progress-bar shows/hides perfectly fine. But adding v-if="loading" to ANYTHING ELSE just causes the element to disappear forever. I've tried adding v-if="loading" to many other different types of elements and it doesn't work for any of them! I tried deleting the md-progress-bar and v-if still doesn't work. I don't understand what the hell I am doing wrong. I feel like the guides explaining v-if have been really straightforward yet for some reason it only works for md-progress-bar......

Comment: you can switch to v-show if you just wanna hide the element, but keep it in the DOM

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue with v-show lol

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the disappearing elements to show when loading is finished? If so:

```
<div v-if="loading">
  <h1> Hi </h1>
</div>
```

This element will only be shown when `loading === false`. For an element to be shown when data is done loading, use `v-if="!loading"`

Comment: I have a refresh button that I click that pulls data from a database. I want to show a progress bar while the data is being retrieved and hide it when the data arrives.